# Error running javac in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, java, ubuntu-11.04

I'm trying to install JDK 1.7 in Ubuntu 11.04 but when I run the following command:

```
javac -version
```

I'm getting error below:

```
Error: could not find libjava.so
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

here is some information about my system configuration for you in order to solve my problem:

The end of /etc/profile:

```
JDK_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_04
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JDK_HOME/bin
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_04
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JDK_HOME
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

output of /etc/ld.conf.so.d/java.conf :

```
/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_04/lib/i386/
/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_04/lib/i386/jli/
```

output of $PATH:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/sahar/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin:/home/sahar/bin:/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_04/bin
```

Please help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your JAVA_HOME is set twice in `/etc/profile`, and the last one is the JRE.  There are also many repeated entries inside your PATH.  Simply remove the JRE and leave the JDK.

Also: this question would be better placed on [Superuser.com](http://superuser.com)

Comment: I changed it still have the same problem. Now my PATH variable is:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/sahar/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin:/home/sahar/bin:/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_04/bin

Answer (score 0):

Your JAVA_HOME and PATH are being written twice in your etc profile, and the second time is overwriting it with the jre JAVA_HOME so javac will not work. Take out the second JAVA_HOME and PATH assignment at the end of your etc/profile and reboot

Comment: I changed it still have the same problem. Now my PATH variable is:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/sahar/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin:/home/sahar/bin:/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_04/bin